# Duplicating row value N number of times Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have data that is structured as "location", "value". I'd like to have the location show up as a separate row for whatever the "value" column is.

For example:  `A, 500` is one row and I want "A" to show up as 500 different rows.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Could you please provide a sample of the input table and a sample of the output you would like? What do you mean by "I want "A" to show up as 500 different rows" — does that mean you want a table with one column, where that column contains "A" in 500 separate rows? Perhaps you can explain more of your end-goal?

Answer (score -1):

This can be done using a number table and a range join.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE numbers AS 
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() as "number"
FROM stl_scan
LIMIT 10;

CREATE TEMP TABLE data AS
SELECT 'a' value, 3 occurence
UNION ALL
SELECT 'b' value, 6 occurence;

SELECT data.value
      ,numbers.number instance
FROM data
JOIN numbers
ON data.occurence >= numbers.number
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

Output

```
 value | instance
-------+----------
 a     |        1
 a     |        2
 a     |        3
 b     |        1
 b     |        2
 b     |        3
 b     |        4
 b     |        5
 b     |        6
```